# Seaborn factorplot to show change over sessions

Tags: python, python-2.7, seaborn

I want to generate a figure that takes in multiple participants' scores from two separate sessions (pre-post) and plot each score connected with a line.

[image]

However, I would like some separation between participants, is there an easy way to incorporate this while including them all in one graph?

```
sns.set(style="whitegrid")


g = sns.factorplot(x="session", y="d-total", hue="subject_id", data=datatx,
                   size=8, kind='point', palette="muted", legend=False) #kind="strip"

g.despine(left=False)
#plt.legend(loc='upper left')
g.set_ylabels("total accuracy")
g.set_xlabels("session")

g.savefig('testfig.png')
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "I would like some separation between participants".